# Получить улицу, адрес и номер здания по latitude, longitude

Tags: php, google-maps, php7, geocoding, geocode

Написал такой код для получения адреса по lat lng, но проблема в том что он возврашает null.И по ссылке по броузеру я получаю "жилое". Как мне исправить это?

```
    <?php
include_once '../apporioconfig/start_up.php';
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$query = "select * from admin_panel_settings WHERE admin_panel_setting_id=1";
$result = $db->query($query);
$admin_settings = $result->row;
$latitude = $_REQUEST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_REQUEST['longitude'];
if ($latitude != "" && $longitude != "") {
    $geocode = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . $latitude . ',' . $longitude . '&key=' . $admin_settings['admin_panel_map_key']);
    $output = json_decode($geocode);
    foreach ($output->results as $result) {
        foreach ($result->address_components as $addressPart) {
          if ((in_array('locality', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types))){
                $city = $addressPart->long_name;
                break;
          }
        }
    }
    $address = $output->results[0]->formatted_address;
    $re = array('result' => 1, 'msg' => "Address", 'details' => $address, 'city_name' => $city);
} else {
    $re = array('result' => 0, 'msg' => "Required Field Missing");
}
echo json_encode($re, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Как мне получить улицу, адрес здания , номер здания ?